# getting diffrent results from a hackerrank bash practice than my acutal bash

Tags: regex, grep

I have been doing some hackerrank practices, mainly about the grep shell command.
The challenge asks me to detect a pattern on bank cards number, which is to detect pair of numbers next to each other, or with a space in between. Here is an example of the pattern :

5678 910[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah0z3.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah0z3.png)234

2[9][9][9] 5178 9101 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efOKH.png)34

[9][9][9][9] 5628 920[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah0z3.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah0z3.png)232

I tried this ERE regex which gives the appropriate output on my bash :

```
>  grep -E '([0-9])([[:space:]]*)\1'
```

PS : Hackerrank does automatically pipe the input file to the grep command

[image: my attempt on Gnu/Linux bash]

However, i get false output, or i strictly saying (different output than my OS bash)

[image: Hackerrank's bash]

Here's the challenge link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-processing-in-linux-the-grep-command-5/problem

my question is:

- does the bash shell on Hackerrank works differently than my OS bash shell ? if YES, then what are the differences and is there any resources that i can rely on. In case the answer is NO, then why the outputs differ ?

Comment: You can check what shell you're using with the command `echo $0`. What is the output in both shells?

Comment: Can you share a link to the challenge?

Comment: yes sure, forgot to do it, i will add it to the question.

Comment: @Tranbi i'm using the bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Hackerrank requires the use of POSIX BRE here.

You can use

```sh
grep '\([0-9]\)[[:space:]]*\1'
grep '\([0-9]\) *\1'
grep '\([0-9]\)\s*\1'
```

The `\(...\)` is used to define a capturing group in POSIX BRE regex.

Comment: one more question : why doesn't accept the ? with a space before it, instead of * Because it does work on POSIX ERE

Comment: got it, turns out it needs a backslash too

Comment: @Ayoub_Prog Yes, `\?` in POSIX BRE (with GNU `grep` at least) is the same as `?` in POSIX ERE.